# How can I bind ListView to view specific properties of a set of objects?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

For those who'd want to know, this is in the context of a tool for self-stabilizing algorithms.

Say I have a few classes, `Algorithm`, `Rule`, `Predicate`, `Action`, `Graph`, and `Node`, defined thus:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SMP {
    class Algorithm {
        public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; }

        public Algorithm() {
            Rules = new List<Rule>();
        }
    }

    class Rule {
        public Predicate Predicate { get; set; }
        public Action Action { get; set; }
    }

    class Predicate {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Expression { get; set; }
    }

    class Action {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Expression { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to connect a two-column `ListView` that will display `Predicate.Name` and `Action.Name` for each element in some `Algorithm.Rules`.

Note the following variable names I'm using for this post:

```
ListView algorithm_view;
Algorithm algorithm
```

I do know that I must set the `DataContext` of `algorithm_view` to my `Algorithm` instance with `algorithm_view.DataContext = algorithm`, but I don't know how to express a binding of a collection like this in XAML.

If it helps to picture it, here is a screenshot of the interface:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your `DataContext` is set correctly on the view, then you can bind your `Rules` property to the `ListView.ItemsSource` property. The `Binding` in the `GridViewColumn` will then look in the class of the type of the collection `Rules`, so we can `Bind` directly with those properties there. You can find out more from the [ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) page on MSDN. Your XAML should look something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rules}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Predicate}" 
                Header="Predicate" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Action}" 
                Header="Action" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

By the way, when using WPF it is wise to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your data type classes if you want your UI and model to update when properties are changed. You should also use [`ObservableCollection<T>` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)s as well for the same reason.

One last point... your title is slightly misleading at present because there is a class in .NET called [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) and your question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Would I use `ObservableCollection<Rule>` instead of `List<Rule>`?

Comment: In WPF applications, that is generally preferable.

Comment: Sweet.  It'll take a little re-architecturing of my software, but once I've got everything working I'll accept your answer---this seems like the crucial bit of information I was missing, but to do this right I'll need a bit of time. Thanks!